# How to use Autowired service inside @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to use `ServiceA` inside `@PreAuthorize` but it doesn't work

**ServiceA**

```
@Service
public class ServiceA {
    public void aFun() {
      return 1;
    }
}
```

**ServiceB**

```
@Service
public class ServiceB {
    @Autowire
    ServiceA serviceA;

    @PreAuthorize("1 == serviceA.aFun()") 
    public void bFun() {

    }
}
```

but it cause exception that he doesn't found `serviceA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Sping documentation beans should be referenced with "@" symbol:  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-bean-references

So, try to use:

```
@PreAuthorize("1 == @serviceA.aFun()")
```